# reading from a file and checking using if condition in python

Tags: python, file, python-3.x

i have a list of URL , and it should be checked with file if the URL  is present in that file it should skip that and move to next

```
             file = open('url','r')
             read = file.readlines()
             lists_of_url = ['url','url','url','url']
              for urls in lists_of_url:
                    if urls!=read[0]:
                       print(urls)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want:

```
if url not in read:
    print(url)
```

That would print each URL which is not present in `read` (i.e. the contents of each file).

Answer (score 0):

It will print the items that are not in the file

```
    file1 = open('url','r')
    read = file1.readlines()
    a = []
    lists_of_url = ['url','url','url','url']
    for i in read:
     a.append(i.strip())

    for item in lists_of_url:
         if item not in a:
              print item
```